# Gutenberg add style attribute using block filter

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to add a style attribute in the block editor to a block's wrapper using a [block filter](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/filters/block-filters/#editor-blocklistblock):

```
const addStyle = createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockListBlock ) => {
    return ( props ) => {
        return <BlockListBlock { ...props } className="my-class" style="color: red" />;
    };
}, 'addStyle' );

wp.hooks.addFilter( 'editor.BlockListBlock', 'my-plugin/add-style', addStyle );
```

Only the `my-class` class name is added to the class attribute but no style attribute. Is it possible to add a style attribute as well? The documentation states:

> It receives the original BlockListBlock component and returns a new
>   wrapped component.

but does not say you can add only class names.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think your syntax is incorrect. Pretty sure it should be `style={{color: 'red'}}` for React inline styles...

Comment: Yes but that is not the issue

Answer (score 3):

Old question but google search leads here first.

You can add style attribute. To do that the style object with the inline styles as object items must be passed to wrapperProps property:

```
wrapperProps={{style:{color: "red", backgroundColor:"white"}}}
```

So, your modified example should look like this:

```
const addStyle = createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockListBlock ) => {
  return ( props ) => {
    return <BlockListBlock { ...props } className="my-class" wrapperProps={{style:{color: "red", backgroundColor:"white"}}} />;
  };
}, 'addStyle' );
wp.hooks.addFilter( 'editor.BlockListBlock', 'my-plugin/add-style', addStyle );
```

That's for the editor view. For this property to be visible in front end you need to save it into the content using the  'blocks.getSaveContent.extraProps' filter i.e. like in the answer above from @BonisTech https://stackoverflow.com/a/60835079/1568334

Be carefull when saving into content. Your script should not modifiy the content without user interaction otherwise the block will become invalid / corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

For the rendering part it's:

```
wp.hooks.addFilter('blocks.getSaveContent.extraProps','my-plugin/add-style', function(props, name, atts){
    return Object.assign(props, { 'style': 'color: red' });
});
```

Couldn't figure it out for the edit function tho.